# Distance between two POINT values in MySQL in a loop

Tags: mysql, geometry

I am storing geometry data in a MySQL Database

```
--------------------------------------------------
| ID | SPATIAL_INDEX | COORDS         | DISTANCE  |
| 1  | ...           | POINT(0.5,0.5) |     0     |
| 2  | ...           | POINT(0.7,0.7) |     ?     |
---------------------------------------------------
```

The coords come from a 2D-Cartesian tracking system.
How can I populate the column DISTANCE with the distance between the coords of a row and the last row?

```
Row 1: Distance = 0;
Row 2: Distance = Distance between coords of row 1 and row 2
Row 3: Distance = Distance between coords of row 2 and row 3
[...]
```

Comment: Assumuing you have all the rows inserted into the table in the first place, and now need to populate the distances then you can for an UPDATE statement that is a self join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL has a special spatial function to calcutate the distance between two points. you can use that plus a join on the table itself to achieve what you want.

```
UPDATE tablename AS a 
LEFT JOIN tablename AS b 
ON b.id = a.id-1 
SET a.distance = IFNULL(DISTANCE(a.coord,b.coord),0);
```